# How to get all classes names for element?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

How to get all classes of element when users click over?

I tried:

```
 @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  click(element) {
    console.log(element.className);
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@HostListener('click',['$event']) click(event){
    console.log(event.target.className);
  }
```